We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors
In my function app in the azure portal I am getting the error in screenshot 1 which states:
We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. I have of course tried to restart the app etc.
Often when people get this kind of error I suppose that they deployed an empty .zip file or similar, but this is not the case here since my function app actually works. All of my functions execute just fine. My issue is that I thought the overview was kind of nice, this error also indicates that there could be something wrong with my setup to colleagues who does not know any better. If I click the See details button, it just says that an internal server error occured in the host runtime, but does not point to any specific error. I did try to look through the logs, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for exactly.
I used to have a setup where WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 and I would put a connection string containing an accountKey in the AzureWebJobsStorage variable.
I would also have WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE variables set correctly. At this time my functions did show up in this view.
But my company is moving to managed identities instead of using connection strings and the storage account file share does not support managed identities.
My setup now relies on setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = https://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>/<function code>.zip where I upload the function code. And then I have unset WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING, which the troubleshooting tool does complain about a little, but I'm not allowed to use these.
I have these environment variables to configure Azure functions right now:
AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName = <storage account>
AzureWebJobsStorage__queueServiceUri = https://<storage account>.queue.core.windows.net
AzureWebJobsStorage__blobServiceUri = https://<storage account>.queue.core.windows.net
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~4
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = dotnet-isolated
WEBSITE_USE_MI = true
WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER_DOTNETISOLATED = 1
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = https://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>/<function code>.zip`
WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = true
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = <conn string>


I have given my managed identity extremely liberal permissions on the storage account right now while I'm debugging this, it can assume these roles currently:
Storage Queue Data Reader
Storage Queue Data Message Processor
Storage Queue Data Contributor
Storage Queue Data Message Sender
Storage Account Contributor 
Storage Blob Data Contributor 

I can also see in my storage account telemetry that my .zip file is successfully fetched using OAuth(MI) so that part is working at least.
My guess right now is that this part of the Azure portal view just does not support showing these functions when I load the code from an URL, all of the functions are HTTP triggers in case that is important. Also the error the portal states about WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is most likely also a bug in the Azure portal, I think it's just not such a common use-case to load it from the URL.
Just providing some useful links:
Load the azure functions from an external package URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies?tabs=windows#external-package-url
Using managed identity to fetch the Azure functions code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#fetch-a-package-from-azure-blob-storage-using-a-managed-identity
Use managed identity for AzureWebJobsStorage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial#use-managed-identity-for-azurewebjobsstorage


Please check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring

@VivekVaibhavShandilya https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#create-an-app-without-azure-files explicitly states that I shouldn't put WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING  it says "You can do this by creating an app without the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app settings." for my scenario where I need to use managed identities and load the code w/o using a connection string.

WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is used only in Consumption and elastic premium plan. as it is used for dynamic scale of functions.

If you do not want to use app setting then you can use app service plan or if you are required to use managed identity, as azure files do not use managed identity follow this document for authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview#supported-authentication-scenarios

I experienced that I was missing som appsettings that the function required for starting up correctly. Adding those fixed the problem

do you remember which app settings?

I was using rabbitmq trigger and the connectionstring was wrong
